# How do I Uncommit changes using git

Tags: git, version-control, git-flow

I'm using git flow, and without thinking, I've commited code to the wrong branch (feature), and then published it.

I need to take that code, remove it from say, branch 1, and move it into the correct branch, which is branch 2.

All the files are stored within one folder which could make things a lot easier, I'm just unsure on how to go about this.

eg.

```
Branch 1 { 
  Commit That contains {
     ./path/to/files_that_should_be_here
     ./path/to/files_that_need_to_be_in_branch_2
  }
}

Branch 2 {
   No Commits.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to move the commit to right branch use

```
git cherry-pick commithash
```

in the branch you want to move commit to.

And to remove the commit from that branch
use

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue, since the reset only happens on the local repository. The commit and pushed files are still in the branch one remote repository.

Comment: you can always push the changes to remote branch using `git push origin branchname`

Answer (score 6):

If you have not published your change, easiest way to do this is to kill last commit in `branch1` (note: this will completely kill anything that last commit has introduced):

```
git checkout branch1
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

then checkout to correct branch and commit your change there.

If you have published change, you can still kill last commit, but then you will have to `git push --force`, which you may not have permission to do, and even if you did, it may cause a lot of grief for other users of this repository.

Instead, you should simply revert bad change:

```
git revert <bad_commit>
```

and redo it in correct branch.

Comment: It's published, so what would you recommend?

Comment: If you are the only user or other users are few and nobody has committed anything since your commit, and you have permission to `git push --force`, then kill last commit and push --force. Otherwise you have no choice but to use `git revert` or another commit that reverts effects of your bad commit

Comment: If in doubt, don't use --force. `git revert` and be happy. The only reason to kill commits (or overwrite history in general) is when bad commit contains sensitive information or huge files that should not be there

Comment: Be careful with `revert`. What this command does is create a commit that negates the changes from another commit, just as if you deleted by hand some files or content.  Depending on the order the branches are merged to master, and if there are further changes in the reverted files, you could end up in master with the negated content: that is without the files and content that was moved to branch two.

Answer (score 0):

git reset --soft HEAD^ To keep the modified changes in your working tree.

git reset --hard HEAD^ To uncommit all the changes you made.